# Alchemistry - A study on alchemy

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: Alchemistry, a dash of salt, a sprinkle of nitre...]

(Author Note) A while ago I made some puzzles for a now defunct puzzle hunt project, here's one of them. The answer to this ([and most other puzzles of said hunt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22A+study+on%22+is%3Aquestion+user%3A78764)) is a single word. The puzzle itself is fully contained within the image above. Author notes don't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbols are

> [alchemical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemical_symbol).

We can convert to

> the [atomic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number) of each element

to transform the statements into

> 1. 6 (carbon) + 3⦶ = 50 (tin)
>  2. 82 (lead) +  = 83 (bismuth)
>  3. 50 (tin) + ⦶ = 82 (lead)
>  4. 51 (antimony) + ⦶ - 4 = 79 (gold)
>  5. 47 (silver) - ⦶ = 29 (copper)
>  6. 77 (iridium) + 2 = 79 (gold)
>  7. 79 (gold) - ⦶ = 47 (silver)

We can think of each of these statements as performing alchemy as follows:

> Starting with one element, apply some transformations to obtain a different element.

Based on statements 2 and 6, we can infer that

> Applying a multiple of  changes the element's atomic number by that multiple.

Turning our attention to statements 3, 4, and 7, it appears that

> Applying a multiple of ⦶ changes the element's atomic number by that multiple of 32.

Finally, from statements 1 and 5, we learn that

> Applying ⦶ still results in a large change, but with a smaller magnitude than 32.

These rules could be visualized if

> we placed the elements in unequal rows based on atomic number and viewed  and ⦶ as horizontal and vertical movement, respectively.

Of course, there is a well known way to do this:

> The [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table).
>
>  [image: periodic table]

This gives us the proper way to interpret the 7 statements:

> 1. Carbon (6 C) shifted down by 3 yields tin (50 Sn).
> 2. Lead (82 Pb) shifted right by 1 yields bismuth (83 Bi).
> 3. Tin (50 Sn) shifted down by 1 yields lead (82 Pb).
> 4. Antimony (51 Sb) shifted down by 1 and left by 4 yields gold (79 Au).
> 5. Silver (47 Ag) shifted up by 1 yields copper (29 Cu).
> 6. Iridium (77 Ir) shifted right by 2 yields gold (79 Au).
> 7. Gold (79 Au) shifted up by 1 yields silver (47 Ag).

Turning our attention to the unanswered statements at the end of the puzzle, we can convert and transform them as follows:

> 1. Bismuth (83 Bi) shifted right by 1 yields polonium (84 Po).
> 2. Silver (47 Ag) shifted left by 5 and down by 1 yields tungsten (74 W).
> 3. Samarium (62 Sm) shifted right by 6 yields erbium (68 Er).

Finally, we can

> combine the resulting [chemical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_symbol) (Po, W, Er)

to obtain the answer:

> **POWER**.

Comment: Satisfying enough to be accepted, although you are missing a part to the puzzle with the salt and nitre. rot13(Znlor guvax bs gurz abg nf ahzoref, ohg irpgbef)

Comment: @Auribouros Thanks, I'll try to work it out.

Comment: As another hint (Gur irpgbef ner zrnag gb or hfrq fbzrjurer jurer gurer ner n ybg bs ryrzragf)